# Long URLs with more than 4095 characters in php

Tags: php, url, file-get-contents

```
$url = "http://example.com/............."
```

The $url has about more than 4095 characters . 
I need to access this URL in php, but if I use `file` or `file_get_contents`, it returns an error

How can i open or access this URL in php?

Comment: Why the bleep would you have an URL that long?

Comment: Please when you get an error, always quote the *exact* message.

Comment: I dont have an extremely long URL to try mysel fbut would a Curl request do the trick?

Comment: Hi thanks. This is a long url that can generate some pdf files . When I use curl to open this url, it returns the error:"'HTTP/1.0 414 Error #10068 - HTTP request line exceeds the 4096 character limitation.
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Length: 71
Date: Fri, 10 Jun 2011 10:03:07 GMT
"

Comment: The odd thing is that that is a server response code, so the people who host this service using only GET fail to put in the infra-structure to sufficient run it. Or, you know, just bad design by people who don't know what they're doing. *sigh*

Answer (score 4):

Your problem isn't PHP, it's the madness of your requirement. :) Also ;

[What is the maximum length of a URL in different browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url)

Surely you want POST instead of crazy GET. This sounds more like a fundamental problem of the systems design.

Comment: Hi thanks, but I can not post this. this is a link that generate a pdf file by a company's url api. they just provide the GET method.

Comment: Then I think you need to write them a stern email, and request them to not create such crap. You can word it differently if you must. :)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on server type, which you are trying to access.

For example:

Apache: limits URL length by LimitRequest*, by default it has 8 KBytes for URL string.

Microsoft Internet Information Server: by default it has 16 KBytes. But it can be changed.

Perl HTTP::Daemon: 8,000 chars for URL length and 16 KBytes for HTTP-header. Values can be changed in Daemon.pm.

Comment: But there is no client, it is php script oO Or are there restrictions in PHP conf too?

Comment: hi, thanks. 
I try the code both at firefox and IE , all return the same error "'HTTP/1.0 414 Error #10068 - HTTP request line exceeds the 4096 character limitation"

Answer (score 1):

the error you got was generated by the remote server ... that service can't handle URLs longer than the stated ammount of characters.

if that API relies on GET requests and is meant to be used the way you use it, your problem is a design error in the used API and has nothing to do with PHP. if you can not change the API or the service that provides access to the API, you can not solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `POST` instead of `GET` for such amounts of data

1. [Create stream context](http://lt.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php)
2. [Set your context options](http://lt.php.net/manual/en/context.http.php)
3. [Use this context as a 3rd param in `file_get_contents()`](http://lt.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

Comment: hi thanks. but I  can not use POST instead of GET.
Thanks for your reference. Can Stream context have an option of the max length of characters? I got the error message 
"'HTTP/1.0 414 Error #10068 - HTTP request line exceeds the 4096 character limitation.
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Length: 71
Date: Fri, 10 Jun 2011 10:03:07 GMT
"

Comment: If you received this from the API server/service, then it means failure is not on your side, but on theirs. I.e. they do not accept such long URL, and no matter what method you will use, result will be the same.

Answer (score 0):

As Raymond Chen once wrote, [if you have to ask, you're probably doing something wrong](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/03/01/1775759.aspx). In your case, you should clearly be using POST instead of GET.